# Prompt display based on condition

Tags: crystal-reports

Logic below:

```
if numberOfDocumentPrints > 0
   // Display prompt - ask to print document duplicate (boolean)
else
   // Don't display prompt - print standard document (not duplicate)
```

Is it possible? Are there any hacks?

Comment: why not just use a prompt that ask.. If more than 1 doc print duplicate?

Comment: Because of an additional step.